# How do you pass PHP string to Javascript/JQuery to use in function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

In my PHP, I have:

```
$welcome = "Welcome!";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">addName();</script>';
```

And my HTML/script:

```
<a id="franBTN"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addName(){
    var fran = "<?php echo $welcome ?>";
    $("#franBTN").text(fran);
}
</script>
```

When I run my PHP, everything else works but my element with ID "franBTN" does not change to say "Welcome!". Am I doing something wrong, or is this even achievable with PHP/JS?

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

Comment: `var fran = <?php echo json_encode($welcome) ?>;`

Comment: Why are you using PHP to output a script which runs `addName()`? Just add `addName()` directly after the function from your 2nd snippet. The problem with your method is that PHP is ran BEFORE JavaScript, so your JavaScript function doesn't exist when it's ran.

Comment: you echoing `addName()` before its defined, browser console would tell you this

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am getting a first name from an API, then I want to pass the first name to an existing element which will display "Welcome, FirstName"! I pass first name to $welcome successfully, now I need to add it to an anchor tag on the page.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I moved the script, and the console shows no errors now. Still not adding the text to the anchor tag though.

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken It sounds like what you need is AJAX. AJAX let's you send requests from JavaScript to a PHP script which can return back to the JavaScript to update elements, etc.

Comment: *In my PHP, I have, And my HTML/script*.. can you explain how the 2 are separate? Is this one file? https://3v4l.org/JbRVN

Comment: It's in the same file. It is a PHP file, my scripts are above my PHP. My PHP makes an API call, gets a first name, I add the first name to the var $welcome. After that, I want to put $welcome variable contents into an anchor tag to display the welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

In this first example `var fran` will become `var fran = "Welcome!";` but when you will call `addName()` will not work because you declare it after..

```php
<?php

$welcome = "Welcome!";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">addName();</script>';

?>

<a id="franBTN"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addName(){
    var fran = "<?php echo $welcome ?>";
    $("#franBTN").text(fran);
}
</script>
```

In this second example `var fran` will become `var fran = "";`, `addName()` will work but it will return an empty string.

```php
<a id="franBTN"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addName(){
    var fran = "<?php echo $welcome ?>";
    $("#franBTN").text(fran);
}
</script>

<?php

$welcome = "Welcome!";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">addName();</script>';

?>
```

This is what you want:

```php
<?php $welcome = "Welcome!"; ?>

<a id="franBTN"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addName(){
    var fran = "<?php echo $welcome ?>";
    $("#franBTN").text(fran);
}
</script>

<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">addName();</script>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are calling function before it is declared. You should call function on DOM ready 
Php Code:

```
$welcome = "Welcome!";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {addName();});</script>';
```

Html/Script:

```html
<a id="franBTN"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function addName() {
            var fran = "<?php echo $welcome ?>";
            $("#franBTN").text(fran);
        }
</script>
```